# i7 edac: ecc error - which module?

Tags: ecc

I'm running a Xeon X3450 on a Supermicro X8SIE-F mainboard. Currently there are 4 reg. ECC DIMMs installed (each 4GB in size; installed as DIMM A-Channel1, DIMM A-Channel2, DIMM B-Channel1, DIMM B-Channel2 - according to mainboard manual page 2-11).

Very recently, this error was logged (and nothing more):

```
EDAC i7core: New Corrected error(s): dimm0: +0, dimm1: +0, dimm2 +3
```

So I assume that 3 correctable errors were detected. But which DIMM is affected?

If I run:

```
find /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0 -type f -name "*count" -exec cat {} \;
```

all counters show up as 0.

But

```
cat /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/all_channel_counts/udimm2
```

shows 3 errors.

There are two csrows listed: csrow0, csrow1

csrow0 labels:

```
./ch0_dimm_label CPU#0Channel#0_DIMM#0
./ch1_dimm_label CPU#0Channel#1_DIMM#0
```

csrow1 labels:

```
./ch0_dimm_label CPU#0Channel#0_DIMM#1
./ch1_dimm_label CPU#0Channel#1_DIMM#1
```

I read

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/admin-guide/ras.html

but can't figure out which dimm corresponds to all_channel_counts/udimm2.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Paul